# ¿Cómo insertar una relación con un stored procedure? - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Estoy intentando insertar una relación en mi tabla de relaciones `UsuariosProyectos` con un `INSERT` anidado. También investigué de que forma puedo obtener un `IDENTITY` y encontré [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row) respuesta ...

> [@bdukes:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row)
>     La cláusula `OUTPUT` de la instrucción `INSERT` le permitirá acceder a cada fila que se insertó *a través de la misma* sentencia ... **evita errores de procesos paralelos** ...

asi que lo implemente en mi `stored procedure`.

---

**Estructura de datos:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Nombre] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](50) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Proyectos](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UsersProyectos](
    [IDUsers] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IDProyectos] [int] NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersProyectos]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DefaultUsersProyectos_DefaultProyectos] FOREIGN KEY([IDProyectos])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Proyectos] ([ID])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersProyectos] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DefaultUsersProyectos_DefaultProyectos]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersProyectos]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DefaultUsersProyectos_Users] FOREIGN KEY([IDUsers])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([ID])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersProyectos] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DefaultUsersProyectos_Users]
```

---

**Stored Procedure:**

```
create procedure insertRelationUserProject
@IDUsuario int,
@Nombre varchar(50)
as
insert into UsersProyectos(IDUsers, IDProyectos) 
select @IDUsuario, Proyectos.ID 
from (
    insert into Proyectos(Name) -- Insert anidado
    output inserted.ID          -- obtengo el ID insertado
    values(@Nombre)
) Proyectos
```

---

Pero estoy recibiendo el siguiente error.

> La tabla de destino 'UsersProyectos' de la instrucción INSERT no puede estar en ninguno de los dos lados de una relación (clave primaria, clave externa) cuando la cláusula FROM contiene una instrucción anidada INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE o MERGE. Se encontró una restricción de referencia 'FK_DefaultUsersProyectos_Users'.

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La excepción que obtienes está basado en una restricción del uso de la cláusula OUTPUT:

> **output_table cannot:**
>
> Have enabled triggers defined on it.
>
> Participate on either side of a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
>
> Have CHECK constraints or enabled rules.

[OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql)

Por tanto, una salida es enviar los resultados de las filas afectadas por la operación a una tabla temporal o una variable de tipo table, por ejemplo:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertRelationUserProject 
    @IDUsuario int, @Nombre varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Proyectos table (ID int)

    INSERT INTO Proyectos (Name) OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @Proyectos VALUES(@Nombre);

    INSERT INTO UsersProyectos SELECT @IDUsuario, p.ID FROM @Proyectos p;
END
GO
```